# Download webpages with javascript dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php script to download some webpages. The problem is that the downloaded files haven't got the dynamic content which is written by javascript.

I suppose I need a javascript engine or something similar. Is there some php library or command-line program for downloading a webpage with all its dynamic content?

Example of what I need: I want to download the webpage `www.example.com/product.html`.

Now: I'm able to download the code:

```
<h1></h1>
```

What I want: I want to download the code:

```
<h1>Title written by javascript</h1>
```

Comment: Please post related code as well.

Comment: Is printing to file an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the JavaScript is not downloaded properly. You are only downloading the HTML file and not the attached JavaScript files.

Once the JavaScript will be available for the HTML page, all the dynamic content would be coming correctly.

**Another Workaround:**
You can use selenium like web automation libraries that actually opens the page in a browser, let the browser execute the js and prepare the DOM. After this you can download the HTML content.

**One more:**

You can make use of PhantomJs to download the HTML page, process the Javascript and give you the final output for save.

https://superuser.com/questions/448514/command-line-browser-with-js-support

Comment: I don't want the javascript files, I need the content generated by javascript written in the HTML.

Comment: A good solution could be a command-line browser. But I don't know if it exists. I know about Lynx, but it hasn't a javascript engine

Comment: You need the js files at least for a while. Even browsers must download the js files to be able to execute them.

Comment: I have tested PhantomJS and it works like a charm. Thank you!